# $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] alternative for post

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting proper url by `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` by `GET method`, but it doesn't work with `POST`.

Is there any alternative to `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` so that I get url of post line like so: `url=www.example.com?id=12&name=xyz&address=pqr`

Comment: check this link i think you find solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php)

Comment: Didn't get you what you want to get it over here

Answer (score 1):

use laravel Request facade `Request::fullUrl();` to get the url of request

Comment: I am only getting  url  http://localhost:8000/machine  but I want complete query string like http://localhost:8000/machine?name=abc&age=20&city=mumbai

Comment: no it is not working.  I am sending post parameter by poster and postman

Comment: solution:                                                                                                    .     $p= (array)json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));      echo http_build_query($p);                                                                                .    output:device_id=r1&x=5&y=10

Answer (score 0):

`$link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";`

This should do the job for you.